# Refresh external script on page change

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a pixel system to track conversion on my website, but when I click on button to go to the next step of my funnel, the script is not re-executed in the new page ...

I've try to do this to give to my browser the illusion that my script has changed, but I always have the same problem :

```
<script>
    pclEv = "PageView"; // Événement de conversion
    function getMyApp()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.src= 'https://www.my.app/initMyApp.js?ver=' + new Date().getTime();
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   getMyApp();
</script>
```

How can I do to refresh my script on page change ?

Thank you for your help !